# Random commas in my HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have commas between my HTML buttons and i don't know where they come from.
The div in which i create the buttons is empty before the buttons are being created.

In my JavaScript, i don't have any commas that could be put between the buttons as you can see below.

Here is a picture:

[image]

I create the buttons with JavaScript like so:

```
    var f = "'";
    contents[0]='<button class="btn" onclick="check('+ f + randomChar0 + f +');">' + randomChar0 + '</Button>';
    contents[1]='<button class="btn" onclick="check('+ f + randomChar1 + f +');">' + randomChar1 + '</Button>';
    contents[2]='<button class="btn" onclick="check('+ f + randomChar2 + f +');">' + randomChar2 + '</Button>';

    ranNum0 = randomize(2);
    document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = contents;
```

My HTML looks like this before i insert the buttons:

```
<div id="response" class="center-children">
</div>
```

And like this after i insert the buttons:

```
<div id="response" class="center-children">
    <button class="btn" onclick="check('B');">B</button>,
    <button class="btn" onclick="check('S');">S</button>,
    <button class="btn" onclick="check('E');">E</button>
</div>
```

If i check in the Browser, it looks like this:

[image]

I checked my whole JavaScript, even tried to delete all the CSS and HTML but the commas remain there...

Does anyone have a clue what might cause this?

Comment: Not random commas, check at the end of your buttons tags and look the comma.

Comment: end of the <button> you have commas

Comment: Remove  commas after button                                                                                                        <div id="response" class="center-children">
    <button class="btn" onclick="check('B');">B</button>,
    <button class="btn" onclick="check('S');">S</button>,
    <button class="btn" onclick="check('E');">E</button>
</div>

Comment: @RiteshK You're missing the point. OP is generating the buttons using JavaScript, not static HTML. The HTML shown here is what the JavaScript is generating so the question is: where are the commas coming from? The answers are below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that you are assigning the string value of your array to `.innerHTML` and the string value of an array has commas between the elements.

In order to combine the values in your array, use `.join()`:

```
 document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = contents.join('');
```

Or better yet, don't use string manipulation to create DOM elements.

Comment: Thanks alot! I have been scratching my head over this for days... Thanks alot sir i am totally relieved now :)

Comment: For others who may have had the same problem as me, you can't just do `.join()`, you need to have `.join('')`. I copied mine from an example on a website and didn't realise it was missing the empty quotes.

Comment: You saved the day!

Answer (score 3):

You're setting innerHTML to be an array, but it's supposed to be a string. Implicitly, `.toString()` is being called on your array, which leaves commas.  Try it out, `[1,2,3].toString()` evaluates to `"1,2,3"`.